# gcc-11 from Homebrew Not Found by MacOS - installation and $PATH seem OK

Tags: macos, gcc, path, version

I'm trying to compile a package called Kraken on my M1 Mac running Big Sur.

MacOS fails to compile: clang gets upset. I installed gcc from Homebrew (twice) and $ brew doctor says I'm ready to go.

My path is now:

/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin.

The gcc-11 etc files exist at /opt/homebrew/bin

But /usr/local/bin does not exist!

MacOS does not update the command alias for gcc:

$ rm gcc

then

$ ln -s /opt/homebrew/bin/gcc-11 gcc

return no error

but then

$ which gcc

returns

/usr/bin/gcc

I'm lost and gather this compiler-pointing has been a mess; is there any new insight here? I've seen a bunch of entries but nothing I've tried has worked.

Hoping this is a stupid newbie (me) problem, I thank you for any help you can give.

Michael

Comment: Home-brew avoids linking binaries with the same name as system binaries like gcc(appleclang). `ln -s /opt/homebrew/bin/gcc-11 /opt/homebrew/bin/gcc` or tell your configurator to explicitly use `gcc-11` via `CC=` etc. and the same for `g++-11` if C++ is used.

Comment: You rock. I believe I know how to do that and will track here what I do.

Comment: OK: This is the loop I’ve been stuck in.  I believe Apple makes this hard to do. 
I try, with and without sudo, to change the links, but it doesn’t work. (See commands in next reply; too long for this one.)

None of the install scripts has CC= tag. 

If I need to do this manually from the CLI fine. I just need really to kick off the scripts or have the CLI run gcc-11 and pick up the required files.

Comment: sorry: can't fix the code formatting?
   
% which gcc
/usr/bin/gcc
   
% rm gcc
rm: gcc: No such file or directory
   
% sudo ln -s /opt/homebrew/bin/gcc-11 /opt/homebrew/bin/gcc
ln: /opt/homebrew/bin/gcc: File exists
   
% sudo ln -s /opt/homebrew/bin/g++-11 /opt/homebrew/bin/g++-11
ln: /opt/homebrew/bin/g++-11: File exists
   
% which gcc
/usr/bin/gcc
   
% which g++
/usr/bin/g++
    So I checked in /opt/homebrew/bin:  ‘brew’ is a script don’t understand; all the Apple and Homebrew compiler types exist there (the listing is too long for this note).

Comment: I haven't compiled code since IBM 3084 System/370 machines, so please be patient with this dinosaur!

Comment: If it's a `./configure` script, you can try calling `CC=/opt/homebrew/bin/gcc-11 CXX=/opt/homebrew/bin/g++-11 ./configure`

Comment: if `cmake` then use `cmake .. -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=/opt/homebrew/bin/gcc-11 -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/opt/homebrew/gcc++-11`

Comment: Also, try seeing where the homebrew gcc link points `ls -l /opt/homebrew/bin/gcc`

Comment: Will advise - Thanks!

Comment: Cannot find a ./configure script.   
The existing script uses a Makefile, and the scripts call make.  
Hombrews gcc points to gcc-11; run the entire thing inside /opt/homebrew/bin? Fine if so...
   
`ls -l /opt/homebrew/bin/gcc`   shows. 
   
lrwxr-xr-x  1 mikem  admin  24 Aug 31 12:24 /opt/homebrew/bin/gcc -> /opt/homebrew/bin/gcc-11

Comment: No script or src calls a compiler (except make, which = clang). No script or src has CC in it.  I'm in zsh; do I need to be in bash?  
Confused, lost dinosaur.

Comment: Should I just go compile this on a Linux box with Homebrew and put it onto the M1 Mac? If that's simpler at this point I will gladly concede...

Comment: zsh is fine, the default now on macos.   The environment variable `CC` is sometimes used by make `CC=/opt/homebrew/bin/gcc-11 make`

Comment: Finally got my ln commands done right; links are good and the correct C++ compiler is running. Now I troubleshoot compile time errors. Thanks!

Comment: Many thanks!!!!  Get the right compiler and then beat the scripts to point output things to the right directory and it's a total win. So many thanks, Mr. Barber!!!

Comment: Let me know if I should add anything to the answer.

Comment: All set: setting the links was the key! Thanks and all the best.

Answer (score 1):

Homebrew avoids linking binaries with the same name as system binaries like gcc(appleclang). `ln -s /opt/homebrew/bin/gcc-11 /opt/homebrew/bin/gcc` or tell your configurator to explicitly use gcc-11 via `CC=` etc. and the same for `g++-11` if C++ is used.

If it's a `./configure` script, you can try calling `CC=/opt/homebrew/bin/gcc-11 CXX=/opt/homebrew/bin/g++-11 ./configure`

if cmake then use `cmake .. -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=/opt/homebrew/bin/gcc-11 -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/opt/homebrew/gcc++-11`

Also, try seeing where the homebrew gcc link points `ls -l /opt/homebrew/bin/gcc`